# Get Amazon reviews in a csv file via Python and AWS

Tags: python, pandas, boto3

Here is my actual code but I can't get through the data base (I don't understand and didn't find documentation how to configure AWS). I got error 410.

Just looking for guide and advices. Thanks.

```py
import bottlenose
import boto3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '146h760vij'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'gikbTElBmA6BexZt8eWKF23apWBbY5fx3Uj2Fpxr'
AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG = 'testest'
 
amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG)
 
def get_product_reviews(asin):
    reviews_data = []
    
    try:
        response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId=asin, ResponseGroup='Reviews', TruncateReviewsAt=1000)
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'xml')
    
        reviews = soup.find_all('Review')
    
        for review in reviews:
            review_id = review.ReviewId.text
            rating = review.OverallRating.text
            review_text = review.Content.text
            
            reviews_data.append({
                'Review ID': review_id,
                'Rating': rating,
                'Review Text': review_text
            })
    
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred during the API request:", e)
    
    return reviews_data

asin = 'B09N9JKM8S'
reviews = get_product_reviews(asin)

df = pd.DataFrame(reviews)

df.to_csv('reviews.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Do you have an associate tag you can use? It looks like you have some dummy credentials 'testtest'. What happens when you use a real associate tag?

Comment: @zouarv42 Hey! Do I understand it right that the AWS access allows you to scrape any reviews from Amazon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 410 indicates that the product with the given ASIN is no longer available or does not exist in the Amazon Product Advertising API. So firstly, you should verify that the ASIN you are using is correct and still exists on Amazon.

In terms of configuring AWS, you will need to set up your AWS credentials and associate tag in your AWS account. Here's how you can do it:

1. Create an AWS account if you haven't already done so.
2. Log in to the AWS Management Console.
3. Go to the IAM dashboard and create a new IAM user with programmatic
   access.
4. Give the IAM user the necessary permissions to access the Amazon
   Product Advertising API.
5. Take note of the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key for the IAM
   user.
6. Set up an Associate Tag by signing up for the Amazon Associates
   program.
7. Use the Access Key ID, Secret Access Key, and Associate Tag in your
   Python code to make API calls.

You will need to use the boto3 package to configure AWS credentials and make API calls. Here's an example of how to configure AWS credentials using boto3:

```
import boto3

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'your_access_key_id'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'your_secret_access_key'

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region_name='us-west-2'  # replace with the appropriate region
)

# create a client for the Amazon Product Advertising API
amazon = session.client('sqs')
```

Replace your_access_key_id and your_secret_access_key with your actual AWS credentials. Also, replace 'us-west-2' with the appropriate region for your use case. You can find a list of available regions in the AWS documentation.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).